# Strong Parameters with Rails Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-admin, strong-parameters

I've built a Rails 3.2 app that uses [strong_parameters](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) and it works just fine. I did this on a per-model basis like so:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
    include ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection
    # Other model code
end
```

My controllers have the appropriate code to permit params hash keys etc.

Now, I want to add [rails_admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin) to manage the models but because the rails_admin controllers are not designed to use strong parameters I get a `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributes` exception, as I'd expect.

So my question is: is their any way around this or should I just fork rails_admin and have a go at adding it myself? I'd just like to avoid that extra work if there's some simple solution I don't know about.

Thanks!

Comment: I bet you'll get a better answer by filing an issue https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues

Comment: Good call. I'll do that.

Comment: Issue added at https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/1347

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get ActiveAdmin to work with Strong Parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13091011/how-to-get-activeadmin-to-work-with-strong-parameters)

Comment: ActiveAdmin and RailsAdmin are different projects. How can this be a duplicate?