# ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError showing even when I've added all of the attributes to the strong parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm having this error on my app.

## ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

I'm using **gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin', gem 'rails', '4.1.7'**

Even when all of the listed attributes are included in the strong parameters on my Active Admin Model.

### Model

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do

permit_params = :prefix, :firstname, :lastname, :password, :email, :membership_code, :birthdate, :contact_number, :location, :active, :confirmed, :remember_token, :town, :province
```

### Error

```
Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"xVA04SdSTDLrwC088FCTRm9fr62z+fgs6wJc0yNn/NU=",
 "user"=>{"prefix"=>"mzxklmcklzmklMAKMDAKLSDMASKLDM",
 "firstname"=>"KLMSDKMSADKLAMS",
 "lastname"=>"MKDSMFKSLDMFK",
 "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "email"=>"KLMFDKDSMFKLSDMFKL",
 "membership_code"=>"MKDFSMKLSDMFK",
 "birthdate(1i)"=>"2009",
 "birthdate(2i)"=>"2",
 "birthdate(3i)"=>"1",
 "contact_number"=>";WE,
LA;SD,
",
 "location"=>",
LDSF,
LSDF,
SL;",
 "active"=>"1",
 "confirmed"=>"1",
 "remember_token"=>"DSL;FSDFL",
 "town"=>"FDMSKLFM",
 "province"=>"FMSDFLKS"},
 "commit"=>"Create User"}
```

Any help?

### UPDATED

At first, I thought it was the birthdate causing the error(it contains 3 parameters and not 1).
but I also have a different resource which also has the birthdate in it and it actually worked.

Comment: Rails 4 uses strong_parameter so this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13091011/how-to-get-activeadmin-to-work-with-strong-parameters may help you

Comment: so this is the whole error, right?

Comment: You don't need equals sign after permit_params.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a typo on the permit_params declaration.  I just removed the equal sign.

## wrong:

```
permit_params = :prefix, :firstname, :lastname, :password, :email, :membership_code, :birthdate, :contact_number, :location, :active, :confirmed, :remember_token, :town, :province
```

## right:

```
permit_params :prefix, :firstname, :lastname, :password, :email, :membership_code, :birthdate, :contact_number, :location, :active, :confirmed, :remember_token, :town, :province
```

Thanks! @nistvan